# One Word Synonym for "Tired" as in Exercising/Running

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single synonym for "Tired" that only fits for the exercising "Tired" and not the sleepy "Tired"? Exhausted would work, but you could also use exhausted if you were very sleepy. I want this because I am making a card game with a word and a single definition. Here is a sample sentence that it would fit in, and another sample sentence that it should not fit in.

**Should fit in:**

After Mary ran 10 miles, she was _____.

**Should not fit in:**

After a long day of work, Gary was _____.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps “***winded***”?

Comment: What did [the friendly thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tired?s=t) suggest which you found unsatisfying? Seems like there are a lot of choices there.

Comment: I want a word that would only be applicable for the exercising tired, and not the sleepy tired.

Comment: If you wanted a word for more than just tired, **bonked** (completely exhausted) would work.

Answer (score 2):

This is as close as I could come up with:  ***Spent***.  The Oxford Dictionaries says this:

> ***[spent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/spent)***
>
> adjective
>
> 1. Having been used and unable to be used again.
>    *‘a spent matchstick’*
>
>    1.1 Having no power or energy left.
>    *‘the movement has become a spent force’*

While this could apply to work or other non-exercise pursuits, I've generally seen it used only for working out or playing (well, one other use, but you're not old enough for that.  8^)